# Sending a notification Via Push API or Push-bullet when a new GitHub release is published for a repo?

Tags: github, push-notification, backend, pushbullet

One problem with our app was that it was published on Github, so the users have to actively check for a new update. Then it shook me, what if we send a notification (automatically) when releasing a new version of the app? But it was a lot complicated than what I expected. I would like to do this via our apps website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup a webhook associated to a [release event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#releaseevent).

The URL of that webhook must reference a server you control, and on which you have installed [dgryski/ghpbhook](https://github.com/dgryski/ghpbhook)

> This is a endpoint for github and bitbucket post-receive webhook notifications.
>   It uses PushBullet to send a summary of the commits to your Android device.

You need to adapt that project in order to decode a release payload (instead of a commit payload).
But it gives you an idea of:

- how to listen for the webhook JSON payload
- how to send a notification through PushBullet